# Create a Proxy by Command Prompt (SSL Certificate)

Tags: web-services, ssl, proxy, asmx, tls1.2

I have a web service(asmx) and it has a certificate for SSL. I can access this web service and see whole methods. I want to create a proxy by command prompt and I am using below code.

> wsdl MyServiceAdres?wsdl

and this is the error message:

> - There was an error downloading 'MyServiceAdres?wsdl'.
> - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. You have to save wsdl file to your local and use below code.

> wsdl.exe myWebService.wsdl myXsd1.xsd myType1.xsd myXsd2.xsd ...